# Extract multiple matches from multiple columns into seperate rows

Tags: excel, formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I have a spreadsheet that tracks multiple criteria. For example, two criteria relevant to this question would be **"Match"** and **"Heroes"**.

**"Match"** is a column that records the Match Number (e.g. 1, 2, 3, etc) of an e-sports match. **"Heroes"** is a group of three columns that records up to three heroes used in a given match.

I wish to create another sheet within the workbook that lists the Match Numbers in which a given Hero was used.

I have this working for a single **"Heroes"** column, and the formula returns the expected result: A list of all match numbers where the particular Hero was used. The formula is as follows:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Match Log'!$E$5:$E$1004,SMALL(IF('Match Log'!$O$5:$O$1004="Hero 1",ROW('Match Log'!$O$5:$O$1004)-MIN(ROW('Match Log'!$O$5:$O$1004))+1),ROWS($A$12:A12))),"")
```

As expected, this formula returns the match numbers where "Hero 1" is recorded in the O column. However, there are two other columns in which "Hero 1" may be recorded, these are the P and Q columns.

*How would I modify the above formula to list all "Match Number"s (in order) that "Hero 1" is used in, taking into account all columns where Hero 1 could occur?*

Comment: An example of your data in text format, perhaps using perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) for formatting, would be useful in trying to help you. Don't add the data as a comment, rather edit your question to include the data.

Comment: Just extending the range to column Q worked fine for me. `=IFERROR(INDEX($E$5:$E$1004,SMALL(IF($O$5:$Q$1004="Hero 1",ROW($O$5:$Q$1004)-MIN(ROW($O$5:$Q$1004))+1),ROWS($A$12:A12))),"")`

Comment: Yes! Thank you, Plutian! That's perfect. I feel silly for not considering it now.